# Creating SQL values from two columns using the selective aggregate of each column

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have the following four tables:
region_reference,  community_grants, HealthWorkers and currency_exchange

[image]

and the follow SQL query which works:

```sql
SELECT HealthWorkers.worker_id
  , community_grants.percentage_price_adjustment
  , community_grants.payment_status
  , community_grants.chosen
  , (region_reference.base_price * currency_exchange.euro_value) AS price
FROM currency_exchange 
  INNER JOIN (
    region_reference INNER JOIN (
      HealthWorkers INNER JOIN community_grants 
        ON HealthWorkers.worker_id = community_grants.worker_id
    ) ON (
      region_reference.community_id = community_grants.community_id
    ) AND (region_reference.region_id = community_grants.region_id)
  ) 
ON currency_exchange.currency = HealthWorkers.preferred_currency
WHERE (
  HealthWorkers.worker_id="malawi_01" 
    AND community_grants.chosen=True
);
```

It gives me the following result set:

[image]

However, my task is to create an entity that includes just 4 values.

```
type OverallPriceSummary struct {
    Worker_id          string         `json:"worker_id"`
    Total_paid        decimal.Decimal `json:"total_paid"`
    Total_pledged     decimal.Decimal `json:"total_pledged"`
    Total_outstanding decimal.Decimal `json:"total_outstanding"`
}
```

**Total_paid** is the sum of values for the specified worker_id where payment_status = “1” (combined for all records)

**Total_outstanding** is the sum of values where payment_status is “0” and chosen is true (combined for all records)

**Total_pledged** is the sum of Total_paid and Total_outstanding (also combined for all records)

I currently obtain these values by aggregating this manually in my code as postgresql iterates through the resultset but I believe there is a way to avoid this interim SQL query and get what I need from a single SQL query.
I suspect it involves the use of SUM AS and inner queries but I don’t know how to bring it all together.  Any help or direction would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I have provided some sample data below:

**region_reference**

| region_id | region_name | base_price | community_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Lilongwe | 100 | 19 |
| 2 | Mzuzu | 50 | 19 |

**HealthWorkers**

| worker_id | worker_name | preferred_currency | billing_address | charity_logo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| malawi_01 | Raphael Salanga | EUR | Nkhunga Health Centre in Nkhotakota District | 12345 |

**community_grants**

| region_id | campaign_id | worker_id | percentage_price_adjustment | community_id | payment_status | chosen | paid_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | malawi_01 | 10 | 19 | 0 | Yes | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | malawi_01 | 0 | 19 | 1 | Yes | 20 |
| 3 | 1 | malawi_01 | 1 | 19 | 0 | Yes | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | malawi_01 | 0 | 23 | 0 | Yes | 30 |

**currency_exchange**

| currency | currency_symbol | euro_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EUR | € | 1 |
| USD | $ | 0.84 |

Comment: Please provide some sample data, in your question, and the result you want to achieve with that data

Comment: Your image and SQL indicates MS Access but you mention and tag Postgres. Are you using Postgres linked tables in Access GUI? Or do you need a pass-through query? This is important because SQL dialects will differ between Access and Postgres.

Comment: @Parfait I inherited an MSAccess database so I use it to throw Queries together and the Queries also works in Postgresql. I happy for the dialect to be purely Postgresql specific though. I guess it would also be useful know how to optimize what MS Access generated though.

Comment: And what is *sum of values*? The sum of price expressed as: `region_reference.base_price * currency_exchange.euro_value) AS price`?

Comment: its slightly more convoluted, (region_reference.base_price  * 
 currency_exchange.euro_value)+(currency_exchange.euro_value*region_reference.base_price  * 
 (community_pricing.percentage_price_adjustment/100)) AS price,      but same idea applies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider conditional aggregation using Postgres' [`FILTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) clause where you pivot data to calculated conditional columns.

Below assumes *sum of values* is the sum of calculated price expressed as: `region_reference.base_price * currency_exchange.euro_value`. Adjust as needed.

```sql
SELECT h.worker_id
   , SUM(r.base_price * ce.euro_value) FILTER(WHERE
        cg.payment_status = 1
     ) AS total_paid
   , SUM(r.base_price * ce.euro_value) FILTER(WHERE
        cg.payment_status = 0 AND 
        cg.chosen=True
     )  AS total_outstanding
   , SUM(r.base_price * ce.euro_value) FILTER(WHERE
        (cg.payment_status = 1) OR 
        (cg.payment_status = 0 AND cg.chosen=True)
     )  AS total_pledged

FROM  community_grants cg
INNER JOIN region_reference r
  ON  r.community_id = cg.community_id
  AND r.region_id = cg.region_id
INNER JOIN HealthWorkers h
  ON  h.worker_id = cg.worker_id
  AND h.worker_id = 'malawi_01'
INNER JOIN currency_exchange ce
  ON ce.currency = h.preferred_currency

GROUP BY h.worker_id
```

Comment: I needed to add  FILTER( where to each use of Filter but it works well

Comment: Whoops! Thanks for that overlook. Edited accordingly. Alternatively, use `CASE` (portable to other RDBMS) but unfortunately not Access *yet*!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
SELECT
worker_id
,sum(case when payment_status = “1” 
      then paid_price else 0 end) as Total_paid
,sum(case when payment_status = “0” and chosen = true
      then paid_price else 0 end) as Total_outstanding
,sum(case when (payment_status = “1”) 
     or (payment_status = “0” and chosen = true)
      then paid_price else 0 end) as Total_pledged
from community_grants
group by worker_id
```

Comment: Just realised this skips the link to the other tables